# Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, charts, undefined

I am trying to use chartsjs to make a pie chart. I have followed the steps in the chartjs documentation and I have included chart.js and the canvas element. i added the script that should create the chart as the example provided in the chartjs documentation. I am getting the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined 
Does anywhone know how to fix this? What am I doing wrong?
Thanx in advance!

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/js/chart.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/js/jquery.js"></script>

    </head>



    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <script  type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
             options = {
                //Boolean - Show a backdrop to the scale label
                scaleShowLabelBackdrop: true,
                //String - The colour of the label backdrop
                scaleBackdropColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.75)",
                // Boolean - Whether the scale should begin at zero
                scaleBeginAtZero: true,
                //Number - The backdrop padding above & below the label in pixels
                scaleBackdropPaddingY: 2,
                //Number - The backdrop padding to the side of the label in pixels
                scaleBackdropPaddingX: 2,
                //Boolean - Show line for each value in the scale
                scaleShowLine: true,
                //Boolean - Stroke a line around each segment in the chart
                segmentShowStroke: true,
                //String - The colour of the stroke on each segement.
                segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
                //Number - The width of the stroke value in pixels
                segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
                //Number - Amount of animation steps
                animationSteps: 100,
                //String - Animation easing effect.
                animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
                //Boolean - Whether to animate the rotation of the chart
                animateRotate: true,
                //Boolean - Whether to animate scaling the chart from the centre
                animateScale: false,
                //String - A legend template
                legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"

            };
             data = [
                {
                    value: 300,
                    color: "#F7464A",
                    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                    label: "Red"
                },
                {
                    value: 50,
                    color: "#46BFBD",
                    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                    label: "Green"
                },
                {
                    value: 100,
                    color: "#FDB45C",
                    highlight: "#FFC870",
                    label: "Yellow"
                }
            ];
             ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
             myNewChart = new Chart(ctx[0]).Pie(data, options);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: found it; Apparently its just ctx not ctx[0] Chart(ctx).Pie(data, options);

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem lies on this line here:

```
myNewChart = new Chart(ctx[0]).Pie(data, options);
```

And in specifically `ctx[0]`. When you defined `ctx` here:

```
ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
```

`ctx` is an object called `CanvasRenderingContext2D`, which haves properties. You are trying to treat it as an *Array* when it's not. `ctx[0]` is therefore `undefined`. So the solution is actually simple, as you have found out.

Change `ctx[0]` to `ctx`, and you have your nice animated pie chart.

```
ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, options);
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/AniHouse/c5nf5agd/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel stupid, this was so obvious and I did not see it. Shame on me.

Comment: The confusion arises from the chartjs documentation. The example for the Pie Chart uses new Chart(ctx[0]).Pie(data,options);

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a little different, as I wanted to have the chart change dynamically (in my application, it's moving with a slider) but avoid the awful flickering.

After standard instantiation, I update on slider drag like so:

```
var chartData = getChartData();

for(var i=0; i<chartData.length; i++)
{
    barChart.datasets[0].bars[i].value = chartData[i];
}

barChart.update();
```

This animates teh change nicely, but after the animation is finished, in order to keep the weird flickering from happening when the user hovers the mouse over (the tooltip is also essential for me), I destroy and recreate the chart on mouse up as follows:

```
if(barChart) {
    barChart.clear();
    barChart.destroy();
}

chartDataObject = getChartData();

var chartData = {
    labels: getChartLabels(),
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "label",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: chartDataObject
        }
    ]
};

var chartContext = $("#visualizeEfficacyBar").get(0).getContext("2d");
barChart = new Chart(chartContext).Bar(chartData, { tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>", responsive : true , animate : false, animationSteps : 1 });
```

The important thing here is not to animate the recreation cause it leads to a very awkward visual effect, setting `animate : false` did not do the trick, but `animationSteps : 1` did. Now no flickering, the chart is recreated and the user is none the wiser.